# Disable caching images

Tags: chromecast

Any way to modify caching? One of the images my app retrieves is updated by the server it seems the chromecast is not checking the image every media load. I'm using the **default receiver** and a LoadRequest to display. If there's no easy work around I'll just give in and make my own custom receiver. Tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the response header `Cache-Control: no-cache`.

Another solution would be to add a timestamp on you image's url, different for each request, but that's less elegant. ex: `myimage.png?_=1426413895301`